# Angular: Object has values, but properties are undefined

Tags: angular

so I'm getting data from my rest service the Dto is filled, but when I try to get to the properties it is undefined.

Here I'm getting the Data

```
this.mapservice.getAllCoordinates().subscribe((data: CoordinateDto[]) => {
  this.coordinates = data;
  this.parseMapCoordinates();
  this.initLocation();
});
```

Here I try to parse it to a number, so I can fill my other Object with it. But the Properties are all undefined.

```
  parseMapCoordinates() {
   let newCoords: MapCoordinates;
   this.coordinates.forEach((coords) => {
     console.log(coords);
     console.log(coords.user_Id);
     console.log(coords.date);
     console.log(coords.koordinate);
     newCoords.latitude = parseFloat(coords.koordinate.split(', ')[0]);
     newCoords.longitude = parseFloat(coords.koordinate.split(', ')[1]);
     this.mapCoordinates.push(newCoords);
   });
  }
```

When I hover over coords it shows me the values, but when i hover over koordinate it says 'undefined' and I don't know why.

[And this is the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EFH7.png)

And last the Dto

```
export interface CoordinateDto{
koordinate: string;
date: Date;
user_Id: number;
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: `coords` seems like an array . pls try `console.log(coords[0].user_Id);`

Comment: coords is the single element from the foreach loop.  coordinates is the array. :)

Comment: but the log image shows as array..

Comment: I tried it, but the intellisense is giving me an error. -.-

Comment: I don't understand this problem, normally it should work but there is always something crazy going on :D

Answer (score 0):

`this.coordinates` is an array of items. so you need to access it with its index, for eg:

```
 parseMapCoordinates() {
   let newCoords: MapCoordinates;
   for (let i = 0; i < this.coordinates.length; i++) {
     const coords = this.coordinates[i];
     console.log(coords);
     console.log(coords.user_Id);
     console.log(coords.date);
     console.log(coords.koordinate);
     newCoords.latitude = parseFloat(coords.koordinate.split(', ')[0]);
     newCoords.longitude = parseFloat(coords.koordinate.split(', ')[1]);
     this.mapCoordinates.push(newCoords);
   }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, tried it as well, but still no changes..

Answer (score 0):

Change the interface to class. The interface does not have initial data, it mostly defines only types:

```
export interface CoordinateDto{
    koordinate: string;
    date: Date;
    user_Id: number;
}
```

to

```
export class CoordinateDto {
        koordinate: string;
        date: Date;
        user_Id: number;

        constructor() {
            this.koordinate = '';
            this.date = new Date();
            this.user_Id = 0;
        }
}
```

and after that, in your `parseMapCoordinates()` function

instead of `let newCoords: MapCoordinates;`
change to `let newCoords = new CoordinateDto();`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response , but still the same problem -.-

Comment: how about putting `let newCoords: MapCoordinates;` in the loop ?

Comment: that won't work because I try to fill newCords in the loop as a Temporary-Variable.

Comment: coords has the data, as you can see on the log-picture, but when i try to access the Property it is undefined.